# How to rename the file and as well as move the file without renameing the file?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

If the file name is `The_Intel_Microprocessors_8th_Edition.pdf (DearBits)` and if I am using `mv` command to rename following error is occurring:

```
$ mv -f The_Intel_Microprocessors_8th_Edition.pdf (DearBits)  Intel_microprocessors

bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

If I am trying to move my file `The_Intel_Microprocessors_8th_Edition.pdf (DearBits)` to another directory, then the following error occurs:

```
$ mv The_Intel_Microprocessors_8th_Edition.pdf /(DearBits/) /home/emertxe/Emertxe_books

bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: is your file name "The_Intel_Microprocessors_8th_Edition.pdf (DearBits)"? If is it. You forgot to put a "\ " before "(". Type "The_Intel_Microprocessors_8th_Edition.pdf\ (DearBits)" or type tab-key while you are typing your file name, so bash will complete it properly for you.

Answer (score 4):

You must quote file names if they contain spaces or special characters that would otherwise be interpreted by the shell. This includes the round round braces `()`in your case.

Use single quotes `''` normally, unless you need Bash to expand variables inside:

```
mv 'The_Intel_Microprocessors_8th_Edition.pdf (DearBits)' Intel_microprocessors
```

or

```
mv 'The_Intel_Microprocessors_8th_Edition.pdf (DearBits)' /home/emertxe/Emertxe_books/
```

The alternative to quoting is to escape all spaces and special characters by writing a single backslash `\` in front of each of them:

```
mv The_Intel_Microprocessors_8th_Edition.pdf\ \(DearBits\) Intel_microprocessors
```

This is also what Bash does for you if you use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to autocomplete the file name after typing the first few characters, but it is annoying to do that manually as you always have to remember which characters you need to escape and you may not forget any.

Comment: Why not just use backslashes?

Comment: Because quotes are easier to use and you can barely make any mistakes.

Comment: You're welcome. Remember that you can accept the answer that helped you most by clicking on the grey round check button on its left to mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have special characters in the `mv` command without backslashes. The proper command would be:

```
mv -f The_Intel_Microprocessors_8th_Edition.pdf\ \(DearBits\)  Intel_microprocessors
```